# Using external helper classes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Apologies in advance for what I suspect is a dumb question, but I can't seem to search for the answer - all I get is results on internal helper classes.

I've got this helper class that takes in a list of postcodes and determines what regions they match with:

```
namespace My.Helpers
{
    public class PostCodeHelper
    {
        public string CompileGeographies(string postcodeCSV)
        {
           //internals that go through the codes and find out what areas they're in
           return string.Join(", ", resultString);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I'd really like to be able to call this directly in the XAML, by doing something like this:

```
xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:My.Helpers;assembly=My.Helpers"

....

<Label Content="helpers.PostCodeHelper.CompileGeographies="{Binding PostCodes}" />
```

That will obviously not work, because the syntax is invalid but it demonstrates what I'm after. Is it possible to spin up an external class, pass in an argument through binding, and use the result directly in the XAML? If so, what's the correct syntax?

Comment: Are you familiar with MVVM concept which is recommended for WPF development?  It is better to implement `CompiledGeographies` as Property of ViewModel and make normal binding to it

Comment: Yes, thanks. That was my initial approach, but annoyingly it creates a circular dependency between my models and my helper class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about converter? You could use your helper class inside of the converter and then just pass your PostCode. Should look like this:

In your XAML:

```
<converter:postCodesConverter x:Key="someName" />
```

Now in your content:

```
<Label Content="{Binding PostCodes, Converter={StaticResource someName}}" />
```

and your converter should implement `IValueConverter` interface. Any probs give us a shout :-).

Comment: Good idea. That's what converters was designed for

Comment: Hah, thanks. I always forget about converters, being inclined to take the name literally :)